# copy and insert row in same table with new primary key+php

Tags: php, sql, copy, row

my project: **PHP**

i have a table. i want copy one row into same table with diffrent primary key.

sql code: INSERT INTO messages SELECT * FROM messages WHERE id='$id'

when i click on submit show :
Error: INSERT INTO messages SELECT * FROM messages WHERE id='12' Duplicate entry '12' for key 'PRIMARY'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you're trying to insert *every field* in that row, which includes the primary key.  If you want to specify a subset of fields, specify a subset of fields:

```
INSERT INTO messages (ColumnA, ColumnB, Etc)
SELECT ColumnA, ColumnB, Etc
FROM messages WHERE id='$id'
```

That way you're not also inserting a value into `id`.

(This is of course assuming that the database auto-generates the primary key.  If it doesn't, you'd need to insert whatever value would be required for a primary key.)

---

As an aside, the use of what appears to be a PHP variable (and explicit quotes) in your SQL code *strongly implies* that you are likely [vulnerable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/332365/328193) to [SQL injection](https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php).  Right now is the best time to [correct that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/328193).

Comment: Can I define a new variable when copying a row?
Can I take new information from the form and replace it in ColumnA?
$ColumnA=$_POST['ColumnA'];

Comment: @morfin: It’s not clear what you mean by that, though it is clear that the pseudo-code you’re proposing is very SQL-injectable and should not be used.